# IIS Web deploy error ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_APPHOSTCONFIG

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, deployment

Web set our dev, test, staging and production IIS 7.5 environments up with web deploy (3.5).  Our production environment uses shared configuration, which is located on a SAN, and configured in IIS with an UNC path.

The UNC path is granted permissions via an AD group, which I am a part of.  I can manually go to the directory, create, delete and update files.  When I try publish a web application from Visual Studio 2012 on my workstation, I get an error:

> Web deployment task failed. (An error occurred when committing changes
>   to the IIS Configuration System. The identity performing the operation
>   was 'MYDOMAIN\MYUSER'.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_APPHOSTCONFIG.)

My theory is that this is a 3 hop delegation issue, where because my credentials need to go from my machine to the web server, then delegated to the configuration storage.  Does this seem right?  If not, what else can I try to get this to work.  If I am right, can I somehow configure the IIS Management Service Delegation to update the shared configuration as a specific account that I know has access?

Comment: In the Connection settings in the "Publish web app" window you should be able to explicitly enter a username and password for an account with permission to create applications on the web server - have you entered said credentials?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen,  yes, my account does have access to create applications and access the shared configuration, I can verify by creating an app manually.  I think the issue is the "3 hop" delegation problem, because there's three machines here, my workstation, the IIS server, and the shared configuration...  I don't think credentials are getting delegated past the IIS server.